# IE7 Rollover Navigation Blocks Disappear When Mousing Over Content

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, navigation

During browser testing at: http://www.interiorsolutions.uk.com

The top navigation includes rollover navigation for building services, exterior services and commercial.  The navigation is CSS triggered on hover of the links and works in all browsers.

In IE7 when the mouse pointer moves past the second link the navigation dissappears.  All z-indexes are set appropriately and even when commenting out content further down the same behaviour is exhibited.

Any ideas would be great?

Comment: tried applying the z-index to the li's or a's instead of the ul?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
#masthead nav ul #nav-service ul li
{
    text-align:left !important;
    float:none !important;
}
```

to

```
#masthead nav ul #nav-service ul li
{
    text-align:left !important;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
}
```

and see if that fixes it